# Difference between GET_INTENT_FILTERS and MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY when querying the packageManager to handle an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-filter

I get different results when i used GET_INTENT_FILTERS and MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY when i query the packageManager. 
Im trying to find the correct filter i need to set. Can somebody explain the difference?

```
final PackageManager mgr = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you specify `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` the call will return a `ResolveInfo` object for all activities that match the provided `Intent`. When performing the matching, Android will only consider activities that have `CATEGORY=DEFAULT` in their `<intent-filter>` definition in the manifest. This is the same matching behaviour as used when calling `startActivity()` on the `Intent`. If you do not specify this flag, the query will return all matching activities, even ones that do not contain `CATEGORY=DEFAULT` in their `<intent-filter>`. Of course, if the `Intent` that you pass to `queryIntentActivities()` already contains `CATEGORY=DEFAULT`, then the flag is not needed.

If you specify `GET_INTENT_FILTERS`, the resulting `ResolveInfo` objects will also contain the `IntentFilter` that was successfully matched. You can access this via `ResolveInfo.filter`.

These 2 flags are not mutually exclusive. `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY` controls how the matching is performed to determine which `ResolveInfo` objects to return. `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` controls what (additional) information is returned in the `ResolveInfo` objects themselves. If you want you can specify both flags like this `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY | GET_INTENT_FILTERS`

Comment: ummmm... How do you even use GET_INTENT_FILTERS this way? Using the above code, the IDE says " Must be one of ...." , where none of them is this .

Comment: Agree..GET_INTENT_FILTERS is marked with "Must be one of..." but I could compile the project successfully. I think IDE is unable to understand it but compiler is.

Comment: @androiddeveloper IDE is broken.

Comment: @DevendraVaja IDE is broken

Comment: @androiddeveloper `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` is not supported by `PackageManager#queryIntentActivities`, use  `GET_RESOLVED_FILTER` instead

Comment: @DevendraVaja `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` is not supported by `PackageManager#queryIntentActivities`, use  `GET_RESOLVED_FILTER` instead